# can't use replaceAll or replace with nextjs/reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using reactjs/nextjs and I'm currently trying to render this component:

```js
const Example = ({data}) => (
<strong>{() => data.slug.replaceAll("-", " ")}</strong>);
```

I get this error each time:
`TypeError: data.slug.replaceAll is not a function`.

The type of slug is a string and i checked it out.
I tried using `data.slug.toString().replaceAll...` that I've found in another stackoverflow answer but I've got the same issue.

I tried using a function istead of direct string ie.: `() => data.slug.replaceAll...` and this time there was no rendering.

I don't know if it would help, but the data I try to render comes from an api through `getServerSideProps` function asynchronously.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely because `.replaceAll()` isn't yet supported in all browsers.

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=replaceAll)

For the time being, you can use a simple [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
data.slug.replace(/-/g, " ")
```

Comment: thank you that totally worked for me. it's weird because the replaceAll works just fine in the browser console. i think it has something to do with babel.

Answer (score 0):

With the deprecation of Node.js 14, it will now be more common to want to use `replaceAll` but Chrome only started to support this on version 85 which dates back to August 2020. Breaking your Next.js application, even for older browsers, seems like a bad idea especially considering the low added value of `replaceAll`. But having the ability to use recent JavaScript functionalities without worrying about compatibility can also be nice. This is where the following fix can come in handy:

1. Add top-level-await in your Webpack config

```
config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true }
```

2. Install `core-js`: `npm --save-dev i core-js`
3. Add a conditional dynamic import in your `_app` file that won't increase your base package size:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !String.prototype.replaceAll) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  await import('core-js/actual/string/replace-all')
}
```

This fix can also be used for any non-nextjs-natively-supported polyfills.